# Sending inline images in email showing an attachment icon before clicking on the email?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, html-email, email-attachments

I'm using the code below to send emails to users, it works as expected. The images show up within the html in the email. But noticed recently that there's an attachment icon that shows up also before clicking on the email. It's a minor issue, but slightly annoying. Having a hard time understanding why this is happening and how to stop it? Any ideas? Thanks.

[image: why is this icon showing]

```
public static void send(String useremail, String htmlBody,Map<String, String> mapInlineImages, String subject, String internetAddress, String websiteFrom) throws MalformedURLException{
        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        String msgBody = "...";
        try {
          Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
          msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(internetAddress, websiteFrom));
          msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(useremail, "Admin"));
          msg.setSubject(subject);
          msg.setText(msgBody);
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlBody, "text/html");
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        if (mapInlineImages != null && mapInlineImages.size() > 0) {
            Set<String> setImageID = mapInlineImages.keySet();
            for (String contentId : setImageID) {
                MimeBodyPart imagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
                imagePart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<" + contentId + ">");
                imagePart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
                String imageFilePath = mapInlineImages.get(contentId);
                try {imagePart.attachFile(imageFilePath);
                } catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();
                }multipart.addBodyPart(imagePart);}}
        msg.setContent(multipart);
        Transport.send(msg);
        } catch (AddressException e) {} 
        catch (MessagingException e) {} 
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {}
}
```

Comment: That attachment icon may just be a feature of the email client that you're viewing the email in. Try viewing it in different clients

Comment: This is probably more a question regarding this mail client. It likely detects the presence of parts with a content type other than text/* and signals that as 'has attachments'. And to not spend too much time, it uses a simple heuristic instead of fully parsing and considering all options. Without knowing the exact client, and the mechanics that client applies **in this version**, it is likely not possible for us to suggest an ironclad solution to this (and likely there is none, and you'll just have to live with this).

Comment: tried it in gmail and in outlook. I get the same problem...

Comment: It looks like you're doing the right thing.  Find another message with html and images that displays as you want and compare the MIME structure of that message with the message you're creating.

Answer (score 4):

add `imagePart.addHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");`

Comment: My code works fine with Gmail, but I had a problem with Outlook client, the image is showed inline but also it is showed as attachment. Adding "image/png" in my case fixed the problem, now the attachment icon is not displayed. Thank you very much.